# Configuring Angular project on Vercel for multi environment builds?

Tags: angular, git, deployment, vercel

I'm working on an Angular project (v17 with SSR) deployed on Vercel, and I have two environments, `prod` and `dev`. I'm trying to configure my project so that the variables defined in `environment.dev.ts` are used, and the build is done in development mode (`dev`) when I push changes to the `develop` branch. Currently, the build is consistently done in production mode.

My project is functional, but I want Vercel to automatically distinguish the environment based on changes pushed to the branch. How can I achieve this effectively?

Comment: `ng build` command by default use production config, if you want override this use the flag `--configuration development` according to [angular build docs](https://angular.io/cli/build).

For example configure a command in your `package.json` to build with development config `"build-dev": "ng build --configuration development",`  and also override default comand into `vercel build` config